# When is ${\log(a) \over \log(b)}$ an integer?

Tags: logarithms

I've encountered this quite a bit.

If I have ${\log(a)\over \log(b)} = c$ where $b$ is a known positive integer, what can be said about $a$ if $c$ needs to be an integer?

Comment: In this case $a$ will be a perfect power of $b$

Comment: Here one should remember that $\dfrac{\log a}{\log b} = \log_b a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then $\ln a = c\ln b$, and taking the exponential on both side you get that $a= b^c$. That is, $a$ is a power of $b$.

Comment: Can $a,b$ and/or $c$ be negative?

Comment: The logarithm is only defined on $(0,\infty)$, so for the equation to make sense both $a$ and $b$ have to be positive (and actually, $b > 1$, since otherwise you divide by zero). This implies $c$ has to be greater or equal to zero has well.

Comment: $\frac{\log(2^{-2})}{log(2)}=-2$ In this example, $c$ is negative.

Comment: @randomgirl sorry, yes -- I was confused and assumed in the comment that $a$ had to be an integer. Without this (which is, I guess, what the OP indeed had in mind), $c$ can be a negative integer (the only constraints are $a > 0$, and $b > 1$.